# can't load grayscale image in halide

Tags: c++, halide

I get an error when I tried to load an grayscale image png format for executing this code. My program is a part from Halide Tutorial lesson 2. This is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "Halide.h"
    #include "halide_image_io.h"
    using namespace Halide;
    using namespace Halide::Tools;
    
    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        Halide::Image<uint8_t> input = load_image(argv[1]);
        Halide::Func brighter;
        Halide::Var x, y, c;
        Halide::Expr value = input(x, y, c);
        value = Halide::cast<float>(value);
        value = value * 1.5f;
        value = Halide::min(value, 255.0f);
        value = Halide::cast<uint8_t>(value);
        brighter(x, y, c) = value;
        Halide::Image<uint8_t> output = brighter.realize(input.width(), input.height(), input.channels());
        save_image(output, "brighter.png");
        printf("Success!\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

And this is the error message:

> Error:
>
> 3-argument call to "i0", which has 2 dimensions.
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 1):

Halide treats grayscale images as two-dimensional arrays, so you access them like this:

```
input(x, y)
```

not like this:

```
input(x, y, c)
```